# On touch video view set as fullscreen in tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I am new to android , developing a small app in Android that is.

in my app video is playing when i stretch the video-view on touch,it should set as      full screen. can any suggest it ,how to do it .

Comment: can you show your layout how you designed?

Comment: just given videoview height=251dp and weidth=490

Comment: ontouch or stretch , set as full screen

Comment: why you hardcode the video view?

Answer (score 1):

//set your parent layout to Relativelayout

```
<VideoView android:id="@+id/videoview"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>
```

//here the alignparent attributes is the important role to do that.

```
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Comment: i want video should play at corner, on touch it should be full screen